# Socket IO with React Native and Headless JS, can't kill it

Tags: android, react-native, socket.io

This is mi first post so I will try to show my problem in a clear way and I'm not an android developer with a basic kownledge of java.

I'm trying to run a socket IO client in my react-native app, as I inquire in order to achieve this I use Headless JS task to have this socket running in the background and even when the app is close, the user recieves a notification.

I have all the flow working well, but the only problem is that when I execute `Background.stopService()`, the websocket do not disconect but the persistance notification disappear.

**index.js (where I register the task)**

```
const MyHeadlessTask = async () => {
  const email = await AsyncStorage.getItem('email');

  if (!!email) {
    try {
      let socket = SocketIOClient('url', {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        query: `email=${email}`
      });

      etc...
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log('[MyHeadlessTask() ex] ', ex)
    }
  }
};

AppRegistry.registerHeadlessTask('Background', () => MyHeadlessTask);
```

**BackgroundEventService.java**

```
public class BackgroundEventService extends HeadlessJsTaskService {
  @Nullable
  protected HeadlessJsTaskConfig getTaskConfig(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    WritableMap data = extras != null ? Arguments.fromBundle(extras) : Arguments.createMap();

    return new HeadlessJsTaskConfig(
      "Background",
      data,
      5000,
      true
    );
  }
}
```

**BackgroundModule.java**

```
public class BackgroundModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {

  public static final String REACT_CLASS = "Background";
  private static ReactApplicationContext reactContext;

  public BackgroundModule(@Nonnull ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    super(reactContext);
    this.reactContext = reactContext;
  }

  @Nonnull
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return REACT_CLASS;
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void startService() {
    this.reactContext.startService(new Intent(this.reactContext, BackgroundService.class));
  }

  @ReactMethod
  public void stopService() {
    this.reactContext.stopService(new Intent(this.reactContext, BackgroundService.class));
  }
}
```

**BackgroundPackage.java**

```
public class BackgroundPackage implements ReactPackage {

  @Override
  public List<NativeModule> createNativeModules(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Arrays.<NativeModule>asList(
      new BackgroundModule(reactContext)
    );
  }

  @Override
  public List<ViewManager> createViewManagers(ReactApplicationContext reactContext) {
    return Collections.emptyList();
  }
}
```

**MainApplication.java (add package)**

```
@Override
      protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
        List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
        // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
        // packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
        packages.add(new BackgroundPackage());
        return packages;
      }
```

and this are the two ways that I writed **BackgroundService.java**
**first one**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

  private static final int SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;
  private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "BACKGROUND";

  private Handler handler = new Handler();
  private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      Context context = getApplicationContext();
      Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundEventService.class);
      context.startService(myIntent);
      HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
      //handler.postDelayed(this, 2000);
    }
  };
  private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "BACKGROUND", importance);
      channel.setDescription("CHANEL DESCRIPTION");
      NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    this.handler.removeCallbacks(this.runnableCode);
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.handler.post(this.runnableCode);
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
      .setContentTitle("Safe Home")
      .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
      .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
      .setOngoing(true)
      .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
      .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
      .build();
    startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    return START_STICKY;
  }

}
```

**second one**

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

  private static final int SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID = 12345;
  private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "BACKGROUND";
  private volatile boolean running = true;

  private Thread thread;
  private Runnable runnableCode = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (running) {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundEventService.class);
        context.startService(myIntent);
        HeadlessJsTaskService.acquireWakeLockNow(context);
      } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(context, BackgroundEventService.class);
        context.stopService(myIntent);
      }
    }
  };
  private void createNotificationChannel() {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
      int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
      NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "BACKGROUND", importance);
      channel.setDescription("CHANEL DESCRIPTION");
      NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
      notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
  }

  @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
    running = false;
    this.thread.interrupt();
    super.onDestroy();
  }

  @Override
  public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    this.thread = new Thread(this.runnableCode);
    this.thread.start();
    createNotificationChannel();
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
      .setContentTitle("Safe Home")
      .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
      .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
      .setOngoing(true)
      .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MIN)
      .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_SECRET)
      .build();
    startForeground(SERVICE_NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    return START_STICKY;
  }

}
```

This problem is giving me a headache, and I can't find a solution, I repeat everthing works well but it seems that the BackgroundEventService don't stop and the sockets still running, I try too many ways to stop the thread but nothing works for me.
Maybe i'm using wrongs concepts or the is an error in my code...

Comment: Did you ever solve this issue?

Comment: i have some problem in the keep running socket.io in the background do you can share your java classes ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59983334/how-can-i-keep-a-socket-connection-alive-in-the-background-in-react-native

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to close the socket by assigning it globally.
In your headless task:

```
const headlessTask = async () => {
      global.socket = SocketIOClient('url', {
        transports: ['websocket'],
        query: `email=${email}`
      });
      // Rest...
}
```

Then, on calling `stopService` we simply close it like so:

```
const stopService = () => {
  global.socket.close();
  Background.stopService();
}
```

Comment: That's right, I fix it saving the socket in redux but that's was not the only problem, somehow my socket disconnet after a few seconds because of the TTL. This is how I fix that

Comment: `socket.on('hello', (hello) => {
        socket.emit('hello', 'hello');
      });` adding this code in the client side

Comment: and this in the server side in order to keep the connection alive `socket.on('hello', function (hello) {})`

Comment: Could I please trouble you for a working example? Whenever the app is closed, the socket ends up dying too with "Code 1005 is reserved and may not be used" I have no clue why